# Using != operator in the if statement to check two conditions

Tags: c++, or-operator

```
char type;
std::cout << "Enter Type(s or c only)";
std::cin >> type;
if (type != 's' || 'c')
{
    std::cout << "NOT VALID";
}
```

I want this code to show "not valid" if the user enters any character other than `s` or `c`, but it shows "not valid" even if `s` or `c` is entered.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Operators in C++ don't work, even remotely, like you're expecting.   If you want to check that `type` is neither of `'s'` or `'c'`,  use `if (type != 's' && type != 'c')`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
if(type!='s'||'c')
```

You need to do this

```
if((type!='s') && (type!='c'))
```

> Why this happens please answer.

`type!='s'||'c'` is `(type!='s')||'c'`, and that's always `true`. You do two checks (you check it against `'s'` and then against `'c'`), so you also need two comparisons, that compound-like construct that you tried doesn't work that way.